# What is English phrase express a time point that happened less than 1 minute?

Tags: american-english, time

Which one below is correct?

1. (Something) added a few seconds ago
2. (Something) added a few moments ago
3. (Something) added a moment ago
4. .....

Thanks!

Comment: The word "*moment*" is intentionally vague in terms of actual timespan. Depending on context, it could mean an imperceptible amount of time, a minute, an hour, a day, a week, a year, an eon ... ; in other words, it's all relative to whatever it's being compared with. There is no *specific* word in the English language which means "*less than a minute*", but "*a moment ago*" will do nicely if the context supports it. (BTW, "a" goes with singular words "a moment"; one would *not* say "a moments", plural).

Comment: Leading on from @Dan's point, it's not particularly common to pluralise ***moments*** in such contexts. It's such an imprecise term there's rarely any need to say *a couple of moments* - and because we invariably mean a *short* time, it would usually be inappropriate to work against that meaning by introducing the concept of *several short (but imprecisely-defined) periods added together*. Loc Ha - in practice most of us would probably use ***just now*** anyway.

Comment: "Just now" is another common phrase that can be used in this situation. Like "a moment ago", it's imprecise about how much time is meant.

Answer (score 2):

They are all correct. If you were to be designing a system that identified that something was added less than a minute ago you might also use:

```
(Something) added less than a minute ago
```

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. I am designing a application

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @The photon. I think "Just now" is the answer in my context - want to say something created/happened at a point less than 1 minute ago.

```
It happened just now!
It created just now!
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact phrase would be:

```
(Something) added <number of seconds> seconds ago.
```

i.e. "New item added 34 seconds ago."

Many applications use this alternatively to "less than a minute ago". See Dropbox for example. Synchronization changes will be shown in seconds (under a minute).